# Rails 3 and beyond: default implicit routing rule is considered a bad practice, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Before new Rails routing DSL was introduced in Rails 3, most applications sported simple, yet effective default routing rule that fit 99% of scenarios and in fact made it possible to do tons of stuff without even thinking of touching routing config:

```
# Install the default route as the lowest priority.
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

If I understand correctly, since introducing of new routing DSL in Rails 3, this practice is deprecated. I know that this behavior can be sort of emulated using [dynamic segments definition](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments), but anyway, there's no "default route of lowest priority" generated anymore.

Why is it so? Any rationale? Current [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) or [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3) explain syntax in detail, but they really don't give any information on why it is considered a bad, outdated practice to use catch-all lowest priority default routing rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `map.connect` in Rails 2 just as you should not use `dynamic segments` and `match` in Rails 3. Catch-all routing is vulnerable to [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). You'll probably learn a lot more from researching this than me trying to explaining it to you but basically:

1. POST requests are the only types of requests that should be able to change the state of an application. So you usually change state through HTML form submissions.
2. Using catch-all routing, both GET and POST requests get redirected to the same actions. This means that you can change state using GET requests!
3. This is incredibly dangerous. Let's imagine that some bank uses catch-all routing. I can forge a url like this:

   ```
   http://somebank.com/withdraw?amount=1000000&from=GreyCat&to=Ashitaka
   ```

   And send you the link. By accessing it, you would change the application state without submitting an HTML form through a POST request.

This is why, in Rails 4, `match` was fixed to only work with the `via` option, like so:

```
match "/users/:id" => "users#show", :via => :get
```

People were using `match` willy-nilly without taking into consideration the problems they were creating by using it. So now `match` needs to be written like that. However, you could (and should) rewrite it as:

```
get "/users/:id" => "users#show"
```

I always like to link to our Russian Rails <del>hacker</del> security researcher Egor Homakov's blog because he explains the security problems he finds with lots of passion and fervour. And he actually contributes to Rails and tries to improve its security so he deserves all the recognition he can get. Here's his [blog post explaining why match is evil](http://homakov.blogspot.pt/2012/04/whitelist-your-routes-match-is-evil.html).

Comment: Fighting CSRF looks like a poor excuse for banning convenient default routing rule. There is only one proper CSRF fighting technique - doing state-changing actions in two steps ("begin" and "commit"), passing a token between them. Whether there would be POST or GET used is not really relevant - although Rails do provide a nice default `protection_from_forgery` filter on POSTs, it's just as well possible to implement it on GETs. Just banning POSTs alone is definitely not the solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to Homakov's posts, though: while his English is horrible and his ideas are, well, dubious to say at least, it seems that I've found what I was looking for. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5960 - this commit clearly shows blatant deletion of code without leaving any comments, adding notes to documentation, adding upgrade-to-new-Rails-version notes, etc. I guess this closes my question.

Comment: I actually disagree with you. It's better that this is not the default route because clueless developers will use it without knowing the consequences. As for that routing rule and POSTs, they were not banned, you can still use them both. The commented out rule is just missing now. Sometimes, a little less magic and a little more explicitness is better.

Comment: Also, while Homakov's methods are a little bit unorthodox (like [taking advantage of GitHub's security vulnerabilities to commit to the Rails master branch](https://gist.github.com/peternixey/1978249)), at the very least he gets his points across. As for his English, well, it's better than my Russian :P

Comment: Deleting parts of code (even commented out) without good and detailed rationale is *bad*. Deleting parts of code to cover up probable security holes without proper security documentation procedure is *extremely bad*.